# Do all particles with zero rest mass and finite energy have to travel with speed of light in vacuum?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, mass-energy, speed

Suppose there exist particles with zero rest mass ($m_0=0$) which are not photons. Let them have a non-zero finite energy $E$. Do they also, just like photons, travel through space with the speed of light?

Comment: Yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massless_particle

Comment: It's unfortunate that that Wikipedia article uses relativistic mass. (It also has some ungrammatical English and poor typography).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be derived from the energy-momentum-relation of SRT.
$$ E^2 - (pc)^2 = (m_0c^2)^2 $$ which for $m_0 = 0$ becomes
$$ E^2 - (pc)^2 = 0$$
$$\implies \frac E p = c \quad(*)$$
Since 
$$ E = \gamma m_0c^2$$
$$ p = \gamma m_0v$$
$$\implies \frac E p =\frac{c^2}{v} \quad(**)$$
$(*) = (**)$ yields
$$ v = c$$

Comment: That derivation is a little shaky because it involves  the [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) $0/0$ in the 2nd last step.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: No, that step is fine. $E$ and $p$ are nonzero. You can take the ratio for finite $m_0,\gamma$ and then the limit as $m_0 \to 0, \gamma \to \infty $

Comment: @RogerJBarlow Sure, it's fine if you take limits. That's why I said it's shaky, rather than saying it's definitely wrong.